# Multiple e-mail accounts using Emacs with RMAIL and Message packages

Tags: email, emacs

I'm trying prepare RMAIL and Emacs to support multiple e-mail accounts. I already have a solution to use different SMTP servers based on the *From* field of a e-mail (based on info in [EmacsWiki](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/MultipleSMTPAccounts)), but I currently have to set the *From* field manually.

What I want is to set the *From* field automatically when replying to someone in RMAIL (i.e. when replying a e-mail delivered to *account1@example.net*, set *From* in *compose message buffer* to *account1@example.net*). I use the Message package as `mail-user-agent`. Gnus have a similar feature called [`gnus-posting-styles`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/gnus/Posting-Styles.html).

What I need, exactly, is something like below:

1. When press `r` or `M-x rmail-reply` on RMAIL summary, look for *account1@example.net* or *account2@example.net* in the fields `To`, `Cc`, `Envelope-To`, `X-Origintal-To` or `Delivered-To` of a replied message and store the first one found in some variable;
2. Already on Message buffer to compose the e-mail, automatically set the From field to the previously stored value.

There is a way to perform 1?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there's a way to do this.

You would need to advise the function `rmail-reply`.

Here's an example:

```
(defadvice rmail-reply (around rmail-grab-to-field)
  "Grab the To field and put in the reply as 'From'."
  (let ((origin-to (mail-fetch-field "to")))
    (progn
      ad-do-it)
    (save-excursion
      (goto-char (point-min))
      (perform-replace
       "^From: \\(.*\\)$"
       (concat "From: " origin-to)
       nil t nil 1 nil (point-min) (point-max)))))

(ad-activate 'rmail-reply)
```

You can find out all about [advice](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Advising-Functions.html) in the EmacsLisp manual.

The above advice isn't perfectly generic, it depends a little on what mode you use for sending mail (I use message-mode and for that the above code works).

A better version would also delimit the extent of the `perform-replace` so that it could only change something in the mail header.

Comment: Thank you very much! That works for me! Is there any way to do it using hooks instead advices or our only choice is using advices?

Comment: You need advice because it needs to run around the current function. There is no hook fired at the right time unfortunately. Here's the link to the source: https://github.com/emacsmirror/emacs/blob/master/lisp/mail/rmail.el#L3746

Comment: Ok, thanks! If you can help me with my other RMAIL question I appreciate very much! http://stackoverflow.com/q/15024182/116001