# How could I use w3m to render HTML content in RMAIL messages?

Tags: email, emacs

How could I use w3m or other to display HTML content inline in RMAIL messages or, at least,  open its MIME part in a external web browser?

The only solution I found is in EmacsWiki but it is a 1996's code that didn't work for me. At least on Emacs 24.

Comment: if you have an example message you could pastebin somewhere? just so I could see headers or something... I *might* be able to knock something up.

Comment: There is a example with a multipart message (a spam I've received :-) and another one with the full message in HTML: http://dpaste.com/995136/. Just save the content to some file and you'll be ready to read it on RMAIL. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Ok. How about this?

```
(defun buffer-html-to-w3m ()
  "View HTML in the current rmail using W3M.

You must have W3M installed for this to work."
  (interactive)
  (let ((subject (mail-fetch-field "Subject")))
    (when
        (string-match-p
         "text/html.*"
         (mail-fetch-field "Content-type"))
      (save-excursion
        (goto-char (point-min))
        (let ((pt (re-search-forward "\n<html>" nil t)))
          (goto-char pt)
          (let ((buf (get-buffer-create (concat "*rmail-" subject "*"))))
            (shell-command-on-region
             pt (or
                 (re-search-forward "</html>" nil t)
                 (point-max))
             "w3m -T text/html" buf)
            (switch-to-buffer-other-window buf)
            (view-mode)))))))
```

I'm not sure about the name and I only tried one of your emails but, for me, this works.

I put your message into `rmail-mode` and then wrote this function, which finds the html and pipes it through W3M.

You're switched to the resulting buffer and we put it in `view-mode` so you can just "q" to stop looking at it.

Comment: I'll try it later and give you a feedback! Thank you very much! I must pay you a beer! :-D

Anyway, I'm looking for a more integrated way, as Emacs does with images and others multipart content. I tried read the rmailmm module but I found the code too complex for me. https://github.com/emacsmirror/emacs/blob/master/lisp/mail/rmailmm.el

Comment: yeah, it would be pretty sweet to have something that really understood html in Emacs. I'm not aware of anything. It is frustrating because the problem isn't that hard imo, it just needs something that throws most of HTML away. Anyway, I'm doing that except for real money :-)

Comment: I just noticed stackoverflow broke my code... I've had to change the regex searches to use a beginning entity. Anyway, as it looks is fine but if you copy the plain text it will be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to take a shot at this using w3m-emacs.